# Изменение форматирования текста button в Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, button

Надо  изменить текст в button1. Нашел пример:

```
this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18.00F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
```

что меняет догадываюсь: "Microsoft Sans Serif", 18.00F-стиль и размер. Но не понимаю, что означает F, где взять все стили и что означает рядок

```
System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

18.00F - это числовой литерал с плавающий запятой, который имеет тип `float`. Если вы, например, уберете суффикс `F` в этом литерале и напишите `18.00`, то тип литерала уже будет `double`. Просто, видимо, эта функция требует, чтобы второй параметр имел тип `float`.

Если ваш второй вопрос касается выражения

```
static_cast<System::Byte>(204)
```

то целочисленный литерал `204` имеет тип `int`, а в предложении требуется выражение  типа `Byte`, то есть требуется тип системы `CLR`. Поэтому используется приведение типов, то есть преобразования выражения одного типа в выражение другого типа с помощью конструкции `static_cast`, которая и выполняет такое преобразование.